# Removing padding from tensor

Tags: pytorch

I have a tensor like:

```
tensor([[ 9, -1, -1],
        [ 7, -1, -1],
        [ 6,  4, -1]])
```

What is the most efficient way to remove the padding and get something like:

```
[[9], [7], [ 6,  4]])
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Your resulting array is non-homogenous, so you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using [PackedSequence](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.rnn.PackedSequence.html?highlight=torch%20nn%20utils%20rnn#torch.nn.utils.rnn.PackedSequence) in Pytorch. It's for batches with variable-length sequences, and supported by Pytorch RNN cells. You can create a PackedSequence with [torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence.html#torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence) method. Please specify `padding_value` to -1 since you're using -1 for paddings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My use case is actually to be able to batch together varying-sized tensors to feed to a GNN. In forward, I will get embeddings from another module in accordance with those IDs in the batch (which come from a subword tokenizer).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do, which requires looping over all values of the tensor in *python codes* -- so I think it may not be the most efficient.

```
padding_value = -1
result = [[i for i in l if i != padding_value] for l in my_tensor.tolist()]
```